# concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor very slow parallelization python

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to parallelize a simple function in python as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import concurrent.futures

def f(x):
    return x * math.sin(x) + x * x * math.cos(x)

xs = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100000)

#This takes about a second
ans1 = map(f, xs)

#This ran about 30 minutes before I gave up
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    ans2 = executor.map(f, xs)
```

I understand that this problem is probably too small for parallelization to actually be effective, but I expected the parallelized version of this to take on the order of seconds, not 30+ minutes.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: are you on windows? Note, `map` doesn't actually execute anything, it returns a lazy iterator over your results. Unless you are on Python 2?

Comment: This is python 2 and windows.  I think that the map(f, xs) going quickly is standard, and more of an example to show that I do actually expect this to run quickly, which makes me surprised that the paralleled version does not.

Comment: Ah, then almost certainly you are creating a multiprocessing bomb. you **must** guard the multiprocessing step with `if __name__ == "__main__"` because windows does not fork, it creates a new process and runs it again, thus you keep creating more and more processes without stopping